# Why isn't this => bounding "this" to the surrounding scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I took the following [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) from MDN.

```
x = 9  
var module = {
  x: 81,
  getX: () => this.x
} 

var getX = module.getX 
console.log(getX())
```

I get `9`:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/es6$ iojs --harmony_arrow_functions index.js
9
```

Shouldn't `this` be bounded by its lexical scope and output `81` instead?

Comment: You are explicitly using a `this` other than `module` when using the `=>` operator...

Comment: *"Shouldn't this be bounded by its lexical scope [...]"* That's exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the below original answer is correct and v8 makes no guarantees - ES6 arrows have *lexical* `this` - this means that `this` is bound to the *surrounding scope*. Your object literal is not a scope.

If you have code like:

```
var obj = {};
obj.x = 5;
obj.foo = () => this.x;
obj.foo();
```

Arrow functions having lexical `this` precisely means that you **won't** get 5 back but instead get something from the surrounding scope. This is unlike regular *dynamic* this which is determined based on the caller object.

---

Original:
Because v8 has a buggy arrow function implementation and it doesn't work correctly yet with regards to scope. That's why it's behind a flag in the first place.

You can track progress [here in the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2700). Meanwhile you can use a transpiler like BabelJS as a build step until the functionality is there.

Answer (score 2):

Because `this` inside an arrow function is bound to the outer `this`:

```js
var x = 9;
var module = {
    x: 81,
    getX: () => this.x // `this` is still `window`, and can't be changed
};
var getX = module.getX;
module.getX();     // 9
getX.call(module); // 9
getX.call(window); // 9
getX();            // 9
```

This is different from normal functions, which don't bind `this`:

```js
var x = 9;
var module = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function() {
    // `this` is `module` when called like `module.getX()`
    // `this` is `window` when called like `getX()` in non-strict mode
    // `this` is `undefined` when called like `getX()` in strict mode
    // `this` can be changed using `call`, `apply`, `bind`
    return this.x;
  }
};
var getX = module.getX;
module.getX();     // 81
getX.call(module); // 81
getX.call(window); // 9
getX();            // 9 (non-strict mode) or error (strict mode)
```